# Error al guardar registro con procedimiento en PL/SQL

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, plsql

Estoy realizando un pequeño formulario en **ASP.NET** con la ayuda de **C#** donde estoy haciendo la inserción en un procedimiento de **PLSQL**, el cual mando a invocar desde **.NET**, el procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
PROCEDURE P_SAVE (
       p_Message     OUT varchar2
                 ) AS

    BEGIN
    p_Message := 'Transacción Exitosa';
            EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
                p_Message := SUBSTR(sqlerrm,1,255);
            END;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_Message := 'Transacción no Exitosa';
    --END;


    END P_SAVE;
```

**ERROR**

El error que me sale al momento de enviar la información o al querer registrar es el siguiente en la función que hago en **.NET**

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error : character string buffer too small numérico o de valor
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La causa más común de ese error es porque se intenta insertar un string con una longitud mayor a la que acepta el campo de la tabla. Mi sugerencia es revisar la longitud de cada valor que se pasa a los campos de tipo `NVarchar2` y compararlos con su correspondiente en la tabla.

Comment: Como haces que un nombre del usuario se autentica `int pidm = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);`  sea numerico? eso no tiene sentido

Answer (score 0):

Si analizamos

[ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small](http://www.nazmulhuda.info/ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small)

explica con un ejemplo que si se intenta insertar un valor que supera la definicion de la variable tendras ese mensaje

```
Declare v_variable1 varchar(5);
BEGIN
  select '123456' into v_variable1  from dual;
END;
```

En el ejemplo define una variable de 5, pero intenta asignarle un valor que tiene 6

En tu caso deberias validar como defines los tipos de datos (o los tipos de las columnas de la tabla) en los parametros del PROCEDURE, ya que le intentas asignar un valor desde codigo que lo excede

La validacion podria ser algo como esto

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GuardarEncuestaDash()
{
    int pidm = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
    var matricula = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerMatricula(pidm);
    var nombre = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerNombre(pidm);
    var edad = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerEdad(pidm);
    var sexo = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerSexo(pidm);
    var nivel = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerNivel(pidm);
    var periodo = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerPeriodo(pidm, nivel);
    var semestre = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerSemestre(pidm, periodo);
    
    if(matricula.Length > 9){
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return Json(new { ErrorMessage = "matricula invalida" });
    }
    
    if(nombre.Length > 60){
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return Json(new { ErrorMessage = "nombre invalido" });
    }
    
    if(sexo.Length > 10){
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return Json(new { ErrorMessage = "sexo invalido" });
    }
    
    EstudianteProfService.GuardarEncuesta(pidm, matricula, periodo, nombre, sexo, Int32.Parse(edad), semestre, 
        Int32.Parse(Request.Params["RMaterias1"]), 
        Int32.Parse(Request.Params["RGrupos2"]), 
        Int32.Parse(Request.Params["RHorarios3"]), 
        Int32.Parse(Request.Params["RInscripcion4"]), 
        Int32.Parse(Request.Params["RCiaa5"]),
        Int32.Parse(Request.Params["RTiempo6"]), 
        Int32.Parse(Request.Params["RProcesoExp7"]), 
        Int32.Parse(Request.Params["RSistema8"]), 
        Request.Params["Comentario"]);
    

    return Json("OK");
}
```

Por supuesto solo agregue solo 3 validaciones, deberias ver de hacerlo con todas las que tengan un limite en el largo de caracteres

Comment: Hola Leandro, revisa mi ultima actualización veo que el tamaño y el tipo de datos de la tabla corresponden a los mismo que le estoy enviando desde el código, que otro error puede ser ?

Comment: Como validas que corresponde con lo que envias? esto se da en runtime, no veo en el codigo que uses por ejemplo `if(id.Length > 9){ error }` tienes que codificar estas validaciones

Comment: En la función donde realizo el llamado a Ajax, `$("[name=stargrupo1]:checked").val() > 0`

Comment: Alli solo validas que el valor sea mayor a cero, no que la cantidad de caracteres no supere cierto numero. Ademas el problema esta en los parametros varchar donde defines un length.

Comment: Puedes indicarme en que parte de mi código tengo el error, en una respuesta para darle validez.

Comment: Pero entiendes lo que explico con las validaciones, no? la validacion que mencionas de ajax valida el contenido numerico, no la cantidad de caracteres

Comment: Ahi puse un ejemplo de como podria ser la validacion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112855/discussion-between-john-doe-and-leandro-tuttini).

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, el error estaba en el tipo de dato del parámetro de salida

Comment: Pero cambiaste todo el codigo, ese no era el procedure que habias mencionado al principio

Comment: Si ves en el parámetro `p_Message` esta como parámetro de salida en el procedimiento, el resto del código no es necesario ya que el error era el tipo de dato que estaba utilizando.